# md2_raid1 takes HDD IO up to 99 %

Tags: software-raid, debian-squeeze

Iotop tool reports that `md2_raid1` takes HDD IO up to 99 %.
The server's HDD becomes busy and it's impossible to do any operation on it.

Here is the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`:

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      1462766336 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      264960 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      2102464 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: What does "mdadm --detail /dev/md2" show you?

Comment: Please take a look the output on http://pastebin.com/3eHUg9uH

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of your HDDs is failing.
check SMART values, test it with low-level utilities, e.g. MHDD or Victoria, or replace with new one and see if it helps.

Comment: Decided to move to an other server with other disks and hardware raid controller.